# update the value of the city combo box dynamically based on the value of the state combo box

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ashx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to implement a dynamic combo box selection system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439419/how-to-implement-a-dynamic-combo-box-selection-system)

I got this question as one of the written test for the company:

> Using HTML / JQuery write code that updates the value of the city combo box dynamically based on the value of the state combo box.
>   You would need to write an HTML page / JS script / ASP.net handler (ashx) page which returns values in whatever format you choose.
>
> Please look at the image for the details regarding the table and conditions.

I couldn't complete as i am a student and haven't worked on ashx or Jquery yet. If any one can suggest how can i solve this problem, that would be great !!

So far i have created a handler which extracts .txt file which contains State and City name in it.

Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

sample code to the first answer;

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
            function Click() {
                PageMethods.SomeMethod(OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
            }

            function OnSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName) {
                $get(‘Label1′).innerHTML = result;
            }

            function OnFailed(error, userContext, methodName) {
                $get(‘Label1′).innerHTML = “Error text”;
            }
        </script>

    <asp:ScriptManager ID=”ScriptManager1″ runat=”server” EnablePageMethods=”true”></asp:ScriptManager>



                <asp:Label ID=”Label1″ runat=”server” Text=”Label”></asp:Label>
                <asp:Button ID=”Button1″ runat=”server” OnClientClick=”Click();return false;” Text=”Button” />
```

In aspx page code behind;

```
        [WebMethod]
        public static string SomeMethod()
        {

            //return cities as Json as suggested by the first answer
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest serializing your info into json to pass the values to your page. To get the values, use the `onchange` event in your state combobox. Upon this event, fire an [ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to your handler, thus returning the data in the success function of the ajax call.

In that success function, populate your second combobox with the data retrieved.