# how to set value of a select input depending on previous field value

Tags: php, html, validation, webforms

At this moment I have a form with 2 separated fields, one of data type to enter a year and a selection one to select to which century belongs the year, so what I'm looking for is a way of having the value of the century automatically assigned when the year is entered, so if the year 1992 is entered, automatically have the value "20th", it does not matter if it's shown back to the user at the php page that contains the form, but it does matter to send the century value on submition.

```
<input type="date" name="pubdate" size="4" placeholder="Publication year, ex.: 1994" required></p>
<p><label for="century">Belongs in century</label>
<select size="1" name="century" required>
<option value="">Select century</option>
<option value="10th">10th century</option>
<option value="11th">11th century</option>
<option value="12th">12th century</option>
<option value="13th">13th century</option>
<option value="14th">14th century</option>
<option value="15th">15th century</option>
<option value="16th">16th century</option>
<option value="17th">17th century</option>
<option value="18th">18th century</option>
<option value="19th">19th century</option>
<option value="20th">20th century</option>
<option value="21st">21st century</option>
</select></p>
```

thanks

Comment: That's the code you're using. Is there something that shows what you tried? Btw, you'll need JS for this, and possibly a dash of Ajax (optional). It can be done in PHP too, but would require more coding.

Comment: I haven't found a code suitable to do it, or something similar that I can adapt, and my programming skills are not that good, so I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4439419/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
 <script>

function myFunction() {

var pubdate = document.getElementById("pubdate").value;

if (pubdate < 2000 && pubdate > 1900)
{       
document.getElementById('century').selectedIndex=11;
}
}
</script>
```

Assuming your input date field id is pubdate and century is the id for selected options
Of course you will need to implement a loop of some sort to accommodate all centuries.

Once you collected pubdate and century you can pass them onto a php file via an ajax call.

Here is an example.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying, but I'm not able to implement it, could you give a little more explanations and advices, thanks

Comment: @ Andrés Chandía Take a look at this

http://deltadigital.ca/pubdate/input-date.html

I hope I understood correctly what you needed to do. When you enter a year and click submit the option selected century changes accordingly. Im triggering the function with a button. I dont know how you plan on triggering the js function.

Comment: And it just works for 20th century only because its just an example

Comment: I just modified it so that it works without a button, it changes automatically on correct input.